# trying to use android NDK/JNI but i get exception UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-build

i am trying to use android ndk/jni but i get this exception when ever i call stringFromJNI();

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.raya.aman- 
A_B2z5nEzTvL2uOtrxLexQ==/lib/arm/libnljnitest.so" has unsupported e_shentsize: 0x9 (expected 0x28)
```

this is where i call the native library

```
public class ToolModule {
public native String stringFromJNI();
static {
    System.loadLibrary("nljnitest");
}
}
```

android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE        := nljnitest
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES    += $(LOCAL_PATH)/ 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     +=  FieldTest.c  log.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS        += -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
APP_ABI :=  armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a
APP_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=format-security
```

i added this to build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}
```

[image: this is where i put the library]

Comment: You haven't mentioned which version of the NDK you're using. In any case, use of GCC with the NDK was deprecated long ago, so you should get rid of `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9`.

Comment: @Michael I'm using the latest version of ndk 21.0.6 how ever i get this line NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9 from a working demo ! so what should i do

Comment: Did ndk-build generate those .so files? Does `file` agree that they're dynamic libraries? Also note that you should use cmake for new development.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the system were looking for libnljnitest.so in armeabi folder which actually doesn't have such library. Have you tried to filter supported ABIs following instructions here https://medium.com/mobiwise-blog/unsatisfiedlinkerror-problem-on-some-android-devices-b77f2f83837d
In your case, the filter might look like this.

defaultConfig {

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a"
}
```

}